# Hangfire duplicates jobs on server restart

Tags: c#, .net-core, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

So we have an .NET Core API which uses hangfire as a task scheduler.

On startup, our API starts the following functions :

```
public void CreateTasks()
{
    /* DATABASE TASKS */
    SyncDatabaseTask();

    /* SMS TASKS */
    SendSmsTask();

}

public void SendSmsTask()
{
    var taskId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => _smsService.SendSms(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(taskId, () => SendSmsTask());
}
```

This creates the job SendSmsTask in Hangfire on startup and does not start a second job until the first one has been completed.

The issue that we just noticed however is that whenever our API reboots (server update for example) the existing jobs are still running and news jobs are being added.

So we would like to remove all scheduled or running jobs on startup.

I've looked through the documentation (http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/) but couldn't really find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem, just note that this is untested.

```
    private void RemoveAllHangfireJobs()
    {
        var hangfireMonitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

        //RecurringJobs
        JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs().ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Id));

        //ProcessingJobs
        hangfireMonitor.ProcessingJobs(0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Key));

        //ScheduledJobs
        hangfireMonitor.ScheduledJobs(0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Key));

        //EnqueuedJobs
        hangfireMonitor.Queues().ToList().ForEach(xx => hangfireMonitor.EnqueuedJobs(xx.Name,0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(x => BackgroundJob.Delete(x.Key)));
    }
```

Comment: Tested the code and this did indeed solve my issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you still interest [Pieter Alberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4268340/pieter-alberts) solution.

**Some little changes on that.**

If you use old code and you have old job in db, you will get Format Exception.

In **//RecurringJobs** section you have to change line like this:

```
JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs().ForEach(xx => RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(xx.Id));
```

**TL;DR**

**Old Code:**

```
private void RemoveAllHangfireJobs()
    {
        var hangfireMonitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

        //RecurringJobs
        JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs().ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Id));

        //ProcessingJobs
        hangfireMonitor.ProcessingJobs(0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Key));

        //ScheduledJobs
        hangfireMonitor.ScheduledJobs(0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Key));

        //EnqueuedJobs
        hangfireMonitor.Queues().ToList().ForEach(xx => hangfireMonitor.EnqueuedJobs(xx.Name,0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(x => BackgroundJob.Delete(x.Key)));
    }
```

**New Code:**

```
private void RemoveAllHangfireJobs()
    {
        var hangfireMonitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

        //RecurringJobs
        JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs().ForEach(xx => RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(xx.Id)); // this line changed!

        //ProcessingJobs
        hangfireMonitor.ProcessingJobs(0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Key));

        //ScheduledJobs
        hangfireMonitor.ScheduledJobs(0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(xx => BackgroundJob.Delete(xx.Key));

        //EnqueuedJobs
        hangfireMonitor.Queues().ToList().ForEach(xx => hangfireMonitor.EnqueuedJobs(xx.Name,0, int.MaxValue).ForEach(x => BackgroundJob.Delete(x.Key)));
    }
```

PS Edit:
My Hangfire version is 1.7.9
and using Hangfire.PostgreSql

Answer (score 0):

```
            //Start Hangfire Server
        var varJobOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions();
        varJobOptions.ServerName = "job.fiscal.io";
        varJobOptions.WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10;
        app.UseHangfireServer(varJobOptions);
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions {
            Authorization = new[] { new clsHangFireAuthFilter() }
        });
        //Remove Duplicte HangFire Server
        var varMonitoringApi = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
        var varServerList = varMonitoringApi.Servers().Where(r => r.Name.Contains("job.fiscal.io"));
        foreach( var varServerItem in varServerList) {
            JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().RemoveServer(varServerItem.Name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HF 1.7.28**

For me deleting *Enqueued* jobs like suggested did not work.
Instead, I had to use the following:

```
hangfireMonitor.Queues().ToList().ForEach(x => x.FirstJobs.Where(j => j.Value.InEnqueuedState).ToList().ForEach(x => BackgroundJob.Delete(x.Key)));
```